# $mdDialog doesn't read from json

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to bind data from a json to an mdDialog but it's not working. Hoping someone could see what I am missing here. The setup is complicated because the data s being accessed in several views. And there are a few other dependencies in play. But here is the relevant code

Service

```
(function ()
{
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.scala-media')
        .factory('MediaService', MediaService);

    /** @ngInject */
    function MediaService($q, $mdToast, msApi) {
        var medias = [];

        var service = {
            getMedias     : getMedias
        };

        return service;

        function getMedias() {
           ...blah blah blah
        }

    }

})();
```

Controller

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.scala-media')
        .controller('MediasController', MediasController);

    /** @ngInject */
    function MediasController(msApi, $mdDialog, $state, Medias, $scope, $document) {
        var vm = this;

        // Data
        vm.medias = Medias;

        //Methods            
        vm.deleteMediaDialog = deleteMediaDialog;

        function deleteMediaDialog(Medias, e) {
            showMediaDataDialog(Medias, e);
        }

        function showMediaDataDialog(Medias, e) {
            $mdDialog.show({
                controller         : 'MediasController',
                controllerAs       : 'vm',
                templateUrl        : 'app/main/apps/scala-media/dialogs/delete/delete-dialog.html',
                parent             : angular.element($document.body),
                targetEvent        : e,
                focusOnOpen        : false,
                clickOutsideToClose: true,
                locals             : {
                     Medias      : Medias
                }
            });
        }

    }

})();
```

And finally the module

```
(function ()
{
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.scala-media')
        .config(config);

    /** @ngInject */
    function config($stateProvider, $translatePartialLoaderProvider, msApiProvider, msNavigationServiceProvider)
    {
        // State
        $stateProvider
            .state('app.scala-media.medias', {
                url      : '/medias',
                views    : {
                    'content@app': {
                        templateUrl: 'app/main/apps/scala-media/views/medias/medias.html',
                        controller : 'MediasController as vm'
                    }
                },
                resolve  : {
                    Medias: function (MediaService)
                    {
                        return MediaService.getMedias();
                    }
                },
                bodyClass: 'media'
            })

        // Api
        msApiProvider.register('scala-media.medias', ['app/data/scala-media/medias.json']);

    }
})();
```

In any other page where it works, I am accessing the name of a media like this `{{vm.media.name}}`...simple.

Here is my HTML (for the dialog)

```
<md-dialog-content ms-scroll>
     <p>
        You just deleted {{vm.media.name}}
     </p>
</md-dialog-content>
```

I don't think there is anything else that could help you. I am not getting any errors. I just don't get any data passing through

Comment: controller opens dialog with same controller - wtf is that? Passing service to modal is also strange - just inject it.

Comment: Dully noted lol. What you're seeing is the results of a dozen tries the smart way, until I started trying the dumb ways. I just want it to work. dumb or not. Preferably not of course. Can you help me out?

Comment: How do you call `deleteMediaDialog` function?

Comment: Fomos the button in several views. Via ng-click

Comment: I know it sounds silly, but are you passing the data when you call the `deleteMediaDialog`?

Comment: The module file has the ability service to pass the data. Code It's in the question.

Comment: Need to provide a [mcve]